# Running two shells at one time using Ansible

Tags: ansible, localhost

I am trying to create a deploy script, using Ansible, that would start and run my frontend and backend server on my localhost. Right now, I have two tasks in my playbook: one that opens a shell and runs my backend server, and another shell that runs my frontend server. I made both tasks `async:259200` with `poll:0`.

In a way, this works but I feel like this is a bit messy. Using this method I cannot seem to further maintain the shells (I cannot shut it down). Does anyone know of a way I could run my frontend and backend on my localhost using ansible without creating two shells that will run for a month?

Comment: start the servers with `nohup` could be one way, then to stop you can come up with a series of linux shell commands with pipes etc, that you will add in an ansible shell task.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use the shell module, but start it with `nohup`, `timeout`, and end with `>/dev/null 2>&1 &` to something like this

```
- name: run shell script in background
  shell: nohup timeout 2592000 /path/to/script >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

- `nohup` will allow you to keep it running even if the user who started it logs out
- `timeout` will automatically kill the command after that many seconds (30 days in this example)
- `>/dev/null 2>&1` will pipe all stdout and stderr to /dev/null so it won't need to post to your terminal
- `&` will make it run in the background

If your requirement is a month instead of 30 days, you could just build a cron job to kill any process with your scripts name on the first day of each month and omit the timeout command.